# While developing package, how to explore my function interactively when there's dependency

Tags: r, import, package

In the following example, my package imports `read.dta` from the `foreign` package and uses it in a function. To check the working of my function, I like to manually step through it line-by-line (i.e. highlighting each line and run, NOT use debugger). However, while doing so, `read.dta` is not actually imported and cannot be used (even after Build & Reload).

```
#' @importFrom foreign read.dta

DDGet <- function(url = 'http://uofi.box.com/file.dta') {
  # Download underlying Polity IV data
  tmpfile <- tempfile()
  download.file(url, tmpfile, method = "wget")
  DDData <- read.dta(tmpfile, to.data.frame = TRUE)
}
```

So, how do I make all the dependencies available during my interactive development?

Or perhaps this is not the correct workflow? I come from an interactive analysis background and am used to stepping through my code line-by-line as such. Is it how one develops functions for a package as well?

Comment: Write unit tests. Unit tests are not supposed to depend on anything external. Instead, you create fake functions to duplicate the external ones you depend on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing functions for a package, or for any external use, I *highly* recommend using the `::` operator. This operator can be used for directly referring to a package's namespace when calling the function.
This is useful for programming to avoid confusion with identically or similarly named functions in different packages.

In your case, `::` has another advantage:
The relevant package is loaded automatically whenever the function is called.
This is useful for checking your code because you don't have to attach the package in advance, and the function will run "as is" (provided the package is installed, which should be the case for imported packages).

Find more info on that topic here:
http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html

In your case, you might alter your code like this:

```
DDGet <- function(url = 'http://uofi.box.com/file.dta') {
  tmpfile <- tempfile()
  download.file(url, tmpfile, method = "wget")
  DDData <- foreign::read.dta(tmpfile, to.data.frame = TRUE)
}
```

Let me know if this was helpful for your problem.

Comment: Your way would be my preferred method as well, but I'm contributing to an open-sourced R package that uses the pattern in my question. Thus I wonder if there's any "trick" to load AND attach all dependencies during development. Plus, per Hadley's book, there's also a tiny time cost with using `::`, so using `#' @importFrom package function` has its use also.